# Why is Dragon NaturallySpeaking sometimes sending a mouse clicks after I wake it up?

Tags: windows-7, mouse-click, dragon-naturally-speaking

From times to times, after I wake up Dragon NaturallySpeaking, and right between the time I start taking and the time Dragon starts transcribing, Dragon sends a mouse click. What could be the reason for that mouseclick?

Looking at the recognition history doesn't give me any clue:

[image]

My computer is configured so that the window key send a mouse click, but I don't see Dragon sending window keys either.

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional, Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: I posted the question on http://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=23705